# Deploying to multiple schemas using Flyway

Tags: schema, flyway

I have a question regarding Flyway and managing multiple schemas. I have multiple schemas (schema1, schema2, schema3) with different deployment schedules and different folder locations (sql/schema1, sql/schema2, sql/schema3) with different code.

I want to Flyway to create the schemas before the code deployment but how do I set this up in a single config file? I read the Flyway doc (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#multiple-schemas) but is the example using a single config file? or do i need to create multiple config files (one per schema)?

Can i achieve the same setting comma delimited schema list? will "**Schema1**" only look in the "**sql/Schema1**" location? I really dont want Schema1 pulling code from a different folder i.e. sql/Schema2, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When using Flyway with multiple schemas, you need to explicitly say in the sql statements which schema the sql is going to change.  You can do this by putting an `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schema1` at the top of each migration file, or prefixing all your statements like `CREATE TABLE schema1.bananas`.
If this is not practical, it would be best to create a number of config files, each with a single schema specified, and a single location specified. e.g.

```
flyway.schemas=schema1
flyway.locations=filesystem:sql/schema1
```

Then you can run Flyway with each config file individually to migrate that particular schema.